# How to solve integral $\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. U-Subtitiution needed

Tags: calculus, integration

How to solve this integral?

> $$\int \frac{x^2 \ dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Comment: Have you tried $x=\cos t$?

Comment: No I have no idea on how to even begin. I understand that I need some kind of U but I do not see any kind of connection

Comment: Then you don't need a u-substition; you need to reread your textbook or otherwise learn about substitution in general, because when someone tells you the substitution to use and you *still* can't do anything, the problem wasn't that you couldn't find the right substitution -- it's that you couldn't execute the substitution when it was given to you.

Answer (score 4):

Put $x=\sin(t)$, then $dx = \cos(t) \ dt$, your integral then becomes $$\int \frac{\sin^{2}(t)}{\cos(t)} \cdot \cos(t) \ dt =\int \sin^{2}(t) \ dt =\int \frac{1-\cos(2t)}{2} \ dt$$

Comment: But then I get the integral $\int \frac{sint^2}{cost}$ but misses out on *cost. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @JavaProgrammer kindly go through what i have done carefully. You will understand.

Comment: $sin^2t+cos^2t=1$ then $cos^2t=1-sin^2t$ which is $\sqrt cos^2t=\sqrt{1-sin^2t}$

Comment: $\sin(t^2)$ and $\sin^{2}(t)$ are different. What we have in our integral is $\sin^{2}(t) = (\sin(t))^{2}$ and not $\sin(t^2)$.

Comment: Still do not get where *cost is coming from

Comment: $\cos(t)$ comes from when you do the substitution $x=\sin(t)$. So $dx$ becomes $\cos(t) \ dt$.

Comment: Fixed my wrongly typed math

Comment: So we are replacing dx with cost? Interesting... that explains a lot. Thank you

Comment: Yes replacing $dx$ with $\cos(t) dt$ don't forget the "dt" :) No issues. Glad to help.